# Rank of an incidence matrix of a graph G with n vertices is n-1 implies that G is connected

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, matrix-rank

I know that when a graph $G$ is connected, it's incidence matrix $A_G$ has rank $n-1$ over $GF(2)$.

However, is it also true that when an incidence matrix $A_G$ has rank $n-1$ that this implies that graph $G$ is connected?

Comment: This statement only holds over GF(2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. If $G$ is not connected, let its components be $C_1,\ldots,C_r$ for some $r\ge 2$. For $k=1\ldots,r$ let $M_k$ be the incidence matrix of $C_k$. Then the incidence matrix $M$ of $G$ can be written in the form

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
M_1&0&0&\ldots&0\\
0&M_2&0&\ldots&0\\
0&0&M_3&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\ldots&M_r
\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

For $k=1,\ldots,r$ let $n_k$ be the number of vertices in $C_k$; then $M_k$ has rank $n_k-1$, so the rank of $M$ is

$$\sum_{k=1}^r(n_k-1)=n-r<n-1\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that the rank of incidence matrix of a connected graph with n vertices is not always n-1. For instance, the rank of a graph which is a cycle of length three is 3 (not equal to n-1).

Comment: You are right. This claim only holds over GF(2)

Comment: Doesn't the claim hold for the *oriented* (signed) incidence matrix? If you take the oriented incidence matrix of a 3-cycle, the rank is 2. If it's unoriented, the rank is 3. That way it's also consistent with the definition and the rank of the Laplacian matrix, which also counts the number of connected components (n-c).